# babel compile es6 class, function not defined

Tags: javascript, oop, methods, constructor, ecmascript-6

Babel is compiling my es6 class so the constructor is a function by itself and the method in the class becomes the class declaration.

This is causing any function calls in the constructors to be undefined.

Before:

```
class myClass {
    constructor() {
        myMethod();
    } // END constructor

    myMethod() {
        console.log("myMethod");
    } 
} // END myClass
```

After:

```
var myClass = function () {
    function myClass() {
        _classCallCheck(this, myClass);
        myMethod(); // undefined function
    } // END constructor

    _createClass(myClass, [{
        key: 'myMethod',
        value: function myMethod() { 
            console.log("myMethod");
        } // END myMethod()
    }]);

    return myClass;
}(); // END myClass

exports.default = myClass;
```

Appreciate any help in this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need `this.myMethod()` in ES6 class constructor and methods.

```
class myClass {
    constructor() {
        this.myMethod();
    } // END constructor

    myMethod() {
        console.log("myMethod");
    }
} // END myClass
```

`myMethod()` calls a function named `myMethod` outside of the class.

```
function myMethod() {
    console.log("external function!");
}

class myClass {
    constructor() {
        myMethod();
    } // END constructor

    myMethod() {
        console.log("myMethod");
    }
} // END myClass
```

JavaScript's method is just an Object's property that is a function. You need `obj.prop` to access a property. In class constructor and methods, `this` points to the instance itself.

Comment: thanks for the help, I tried that originally in the constructor, adding this. to method declaration is not mentioned in es6 docs and babel through a syntax error 'unexpected token' on that as well. Also tried myMethod: function() {}, same result. Could provide code sample, so I can see what exactly you are talking about?

Comment: Thanks that was in fact part of my problem, the other problem I was overlooking is that I was trying to access myMethod inside a callback anonymous function. removing the anonymous func wrapper and using this.myMethod.bind(this)  fixed the problem once and for all

Comment: If you are using ES6, Arrow Function (`() => {}`) is also handy. Inside it, `this` refers to the same object that its outer scope's `this` refers to.

`class Something {
  constructor() {
    someElement.addEventListener('click', () => {
      this.myMethod(); /* 'this' refers to the instance! */
    });
  }
}`